# Why does my use of zlib decompress incorrectly?

Tags: c++, zlib

Please explain if this is a Zlib bug or I misunderstand the use of Zlib.

I am trying to do the following:

-I have two strings - data from which I need to compress: string_data_1 and string_data_2 and which I compress with Zlib as **raw** data.

-Next, I create a third string and copy the already compressed data into this single row.

-Now I'm decompressing this combined compressed data and there is a problem.

Zlib decompressed only the "first" part of the compressed data, did not decompress the second part. Is that how it should be?

**For an example** in the **facebook/zstd:Zstandard** library - exactly the same action - leads to unpacking - all compressed data and the first and second parts.

Here is a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <zlib.h>




int my_Zlib__compress__RAW(std::string& string_data_to_be_compressed, std::string& string_compressed_result, int level_compressed)
{

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    uLong zlib_uLong = compressBound(string_data_to_be_compressed.size());         

    string_compressed_result.resize(zlib_uLong);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------


     //this is the standard Zlib compress2 function - with one exception: the deflateInit2 function is used instead of the deflateInit function and the windowBits parameter is set to "-15" so that Zlib compresses the data as raw data:
    int status = my_compress2((Bytef*)&string_compressed_result[0], &zlib_uLong, (const Bytef*)&string_data_to_be_compressed[0], string_data_to_be_compressed.size(), level_compressed);



    if (status == Z_OK)
    {
        string_compressed_result.resize(zlib_uLong);     

        return 0;
    }
        else
        { 
        return 1;
        }

}

int my_Zlib__uncompress__RAW(std::string& string_data_to_be_uncompressed, std::string& string_compressed_data, size_t size_uncompressed_data)
{

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    string_data_to_be_uncompressed.resize(size_uncompressed_data);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //this is the standard Zlib uncompress function - with one exception: the inflateInit2 function is used instead of the inflateInit function and the windowBits parameter is set to "-15" so that Zlib uncompresses the data as raw data:
    int status = my_uncompress((Bytef*)&string_data_to_be_uncompressed[0], (uLongf*)&size_uncompressed_data, (const Bytef*)&string_compressed_data[0], string_compressed_data.size());   

    if (status == Z_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}




int main()
{

int level_compressed = 9;     


//------------------------------------------Compress_1-------------------------------------------
std::string string_data_1 = "Hello12_Hello12_Hello125";              //The data to be compressed.

std::string string_compressed_result_RAW_1;                             //Compressed data will be written here

int status = my_Zlib__compress__RAW(string_data_1 , string_compressed_result_RAW_1, level_compressed);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//--------------------------------------Compress_2----------------------------------------------
std::string string_data_2= "BUY22_BUY22_BUY223";              //The data to be compressed.

std::string string_compressed_result_RAW_2;                         //Compressed data will be written here

status = my_Zlib__compress__RAW(string_data_2 , string_compressed_result_RAW_2, level_compressed);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


std::string Total_compressed_data = string_compressed_result_RAW_1 + string_compressed_result_RAW_2; //Combine two compressed data into one string

//Now I want to uncompress the data in a string - "Total_compressed_data"


//--------------------------------------Uncompress--------------------------------
std::string string_uncompressed_result_RAW;                         //Uncompressed data will be written here

int size_that_should_be_when_unpacking = string_data_1.size() + string_data_2.size();

status = my_Zlib__uncompress__RAW(string_uncompressed_result_RAW, Total_compressed_data, size_that_should_be_when_unpacking , level_compressed);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::cout<<string_uncompressed_result_RAW<<std::endl;  //Hello12_Hello12_Hello125

}
```

Zlib decompressed only the "first" part of the compressed data, did not decompress the "second" part.

Is that how it should be?

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed that concatenation of two compressed strings is a compressed string. For example, `zlib` may expect some metadata in the beginning of the compressed data. So you probably cannot concatenate compressed strings as is.

Comment: I don't know zlib well enough but I have to think that yeputons is right. zlib is a very widely used library, you'd struggle to find one that is more widely used. So the chance that you have found a bug with such a simple program is 1000000 to 1, and that's probably being generous.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: @john, I didn't claim it was a bug. I asked, is this how it should be? Why can't Zlib unpack all the raw data? For example "zstd" can do this.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil,  Zlib is C.

Comment: @Serg_ You did pose the question, and I didn;t say it wasn't bug, just that it was unlikely. Libraries differ in their designs, just because one library has a certain feature doesn't not mean that another has to have it as well. I guess the designers of zlib didn't think that this feature was useful enough to work into their compression algorithms. Having this feature will have a cost, on the compression performance.

Comment: @john, How can i know for sure?

Comment: @Serg_: The language Zlib is implemented in is irrelevant. You are calling it using C++ code. There is no question of C language rules here. Arguably, there is no question of C++ language rules either, so the question should probably not be tagged C++ either.

Comment: @Serg_ Well the first place to look would be the official zlib documentation. Or maybe wait for some expert to answer this question.

Comment: Note that `compress()` and `compress2()` are convenience calls, provided as an easy shortcut for when you have all the data you want to compress pre-assembled inside a single buffer.  If you want to build up a compressed-data buffer across multiple calls, you need to use the main zlib API (`deflateInit()`/`deflate()`/`deflateEnd()`) instead.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesne, I used them - see the comments on the my_compress2 and my_uncompress functions. I just did not insert the code of these functions.

Comment: You need to post code that can be compiled. You need to include your `my_`... functions, and your `my_Zlib__uncompress__RAW()` definition has three arguments, but you try to call it with four, and it doesn't always return a value. Please only post code that is copied directly from code that you have successfully compiled and run.

Comment: @Serg_ it's not easy to see those comments, on my screen I have to scroll way to the right in order to know they exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a concatenation of zlib streams is not a zlib stream. You need to uncompress again for the second zlib stream. Or compress the whole thing as one zlib stream in the first place.

You would need to use a variant of `uncompress2()`, not `uncompress()`, since the former will return the size of the first decompressed zlib stream in the last parameter, so that you know where to start decompressing the second one.

Better yet, you should use the `inflate()` functions instead for your application. The retention of the uncompressed size for use in decompression means that you'd need that on the other end. How do you get that? Are you transmitting it separately? You do not need that. You should use `inflate()` to decompress a chunk at a time, and then you don't need to know the uncompressed size ahead of time.

You should also use the `deflate()` functions for compression. Then you can keep the stream open, and keep compressing until you're done. Then you will have a single zlib stream.

Comment: Thank you! As a result, to unpack the concatenated compressed data, I managed to use: inflateInit2, inflate and the most important field total_in of the z_stream structure, which I used to offset when unpacking the concatenated compressed data